# I have installed SQL Server and Managment Studio on laptop but server name has gone

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, configuration

The other week I installed the latest version of SQL Server and Management Studio. In the Server Name box was a long name made up of some path and other parts however it has now disappeared and reading all these answers has not helped. I downloaded two backups of databases from a live server and restored them down here. I could access them and everything was fine until the server name disappeared and I have no idea (none of the ones on here work) how to get it back.

1. If I try `localhost`, `127.1.1.0` or `.` as the server name it doesn't work the error I get is:

   > A network or instance-specific occurred whilst establishing connection to SQL Server....Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40- could not open connection to SQL Server

If I go into services I only have SQL Server Browser and SQL Server VSS Writer. Under Browser it is disabled. If I start it or tell it to start on delayed or manual or just start it, it starts okay and then two seconds later its stopped again with no error message.

If I got to CMD and type (under) I get (under that)

```
C:\Windows\system32>SQLCMD -L

Servers:

    ;UID:Login ID=?;PWD:Password=?;Trusted_Connection:Use Integrated Security=?;
*APP:AppName=?;*WSID:WorkStation ID=?;
```

No list of servers which another answer suggested.

I cannot find under services a MS SQL Service for some reason.

Everything was working fine the last time I came to do some work on this so I don't know if some virus was detected that removed the service or something.

I had two databases to connect to and run queries against and try to get a Windows Service working again locally but I can't get the DB to work.

I am on Windows 8.1 64bit laptop with enough diskspace.

If I go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\LocalDB\Binn` and double click `sqlservr.exe`, I get the error

> Your SQL Server Installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (Error getting Instance ID from name) Please uninstall then re-run setup to correct this problem.

Is it a case of me having to uninstall Management Studio and restarting again? I don't know what could have corrupted it but I need it working.

Should I just use the SQL Server 2017 Configuration Server to see if that can fix it or do I need to delete whole directories or "uninstall" from "programs and features" and try to install it again?

Still have no scooby to why the server name disappeared in the first place. Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server should appear in Services (you should not start it by double-clicking sqlservr.exe). If it doesn't appear anymore, you should reinstall SQL Server. After that you may attach the MDF and LDF files of your user databases, if they are still available (but in your case, you can also restore the backups again).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your SQL server is not installed properly or corrupted now.

If the SQL Server installs on any machine there is a service named 'Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER)' or similar must be there and in 'Running' mode to connect to the database.